# NoUiSlider is not emitting correct values when sliding and using keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

```
{ 
start:[431,1425],
connect:true,
step:15,
range:{
  'min':431,
  'max':1425
},
keyboard:true
}
```

I am using above config for noUiSlider. Using the slider for time.

Currently the values are **7:11 - 23:45**.
When I am sliding it from right handle the value should be **23:30** but it is emitting **23:41**

Below is the JS fiddle for same.

https://jsfiddle.net/lamp03/ad1b5ver/1/

However if I change the left handle value from 431 to 435 in config then it is emitting the expected value.

Any help or leads will be appreciated.

Comment: The version of noUiSlider in your jsfiddle is 8.2.1, while the most recent release is 14.0.2.

Comment: And have you found solution? I'm interested in if exists another one than my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain it, in my opinion this is because the slider divides the distance between the beginning and the end into equal parts. If from 23:45 you go back every 15 minutes you will not get 7:11, only 7:15, so in the first move the slider is set so as to get 7:11 in the last move. In `nouislider` slidres can't exceed their limit. Look that, If you go from left to right last move is by 4 not by 15, from 1421 to 1425, because left zip cannot exceed right one.

Comment: This is correct. (1425-435)/15 = 66 (so complete steps), while (1425-431)/15 = 66.26.